# Laravel registercontroller, add another create

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel auth to handle my login/register/validation etc. Now i need to after creating the user at register also create another table containing the user->id.

Something like this is what i would like to achieve, obviously this doesnt work but you get what im after. Is this possible or is my only option to create a custom registercontroller for my needs?

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;


    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User && \App\Stats
     */ 
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return [
          User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]),
            Stats::create([
              'user_id' => $user->id
            ])
          ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Stats::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```